# Why do we use で in 東京での暮らし?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-で

> 車椅子利用者からすると、東京での暮らしは便利とはいえない。

Why do we use で after 東京? Is it to show the action in the place? What if we only say 東京の暮らしは?